# Neo4j Cypher return combination of matched nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'd like to do some analytics over the database with the following schema:

[image]

As you may see on the picture above, there is a `Vacancy1` which requires knowledge of `Java` and `Python` and proposes the salary equals `5000$`. Also, there is a set of candidates which know everything (like `Candidate5`) a suit the salary (`Cadidate5` desired salary equals `4950$`), and candidates which know some skills, like only `Java` or `Python` but together know everything what is required on the vacancy, for example:

```
Candidate1(Java, 2000$), Candidate2(Python, 1500$)
```

such set of candidates together know `Java` and `Python` and a united salary is equal `3500$`.

Is it possible to write the query in Neo4j in order to find all possible sets of candidates which suite such vacancy condition?

For example, for the picture above the result should contain, something like that:

```
[candidate5],
[candidate1, candidate2],
[candidate1, candidate4],
[candidate3, candidate2]
```

Please note, that the combinations of the candidates in the result may contain any number of candidates and not limited to only 1 or 2 as in the example above.

Could you please show an example of such Cypher query?

**UPDATED**

What if I need to take into account some additional properties, like for example experience, like `minExp` on the diagram below:

[image]

Here, we need a candidate for the `Vacancy1` with `minExp = 3`
The `Candidate2` has `exp (experience) = 2` and is not a good fit from Java point of view, but in pair with `Candidate3(exp = 5)`, they together is a good fit for the `Vacancy1`. Is it possible to improve the query in order to take this information into account and do such combinations?

Answer (score 3):

I am a fan of NEO4J APOC functions so in APOC, theres is a function that gives all possble combinations on a given list. It returns a list of list with 1 or 2 or 3 or n items.

```
 With ["Java", "Python"] as skills, size(skills) as n
 Match (v:Vacancy)-[:CONTAINS]->(s:Skills)<-[:CONTAINS]-(c:Candidate)
 Where s.language in skills and v.salary <= c.salary
 With n, v, collect(c) as candidates
 With v, apoc.coll.combinations(candidates, 1, n) as allCandidatesCombi
 Unwind allCandidatesCombi as combi
 With v, combi where apoc.coll.sum([c in combi |combi.salary]) <= v.salary
 Return v, combi

 References:
 n is number of skills or candidates in the result
 apoc.coll.combinations will give you all possible combinations of all candidates with 1 to n candiates
 Unwind is like a for loop and gives you each item of that list one at a time
 apoc.coll.sum will sum up the candidates salary
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I need a time to test it.

Comment: What about the performance of such approach? What if I have 50k candidates.. the combination of such candidates may overflow the system?

Comment: Also, could you please take a look into my updated question? I'm strugling with this all of the day. Thanks!